# Logistic Regression in Jupyter Notebook; Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science, logistic-regression

I want to create a logistic regression model to predict if the relationship is known or unknown, I've set the known values to 1 and unknown to 0 in the dataset. I have also added several features to train the data and predict the relationship.

I have run this code:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    %matplotlib inline
    import sklearn.datasets
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv('boo.csv')
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    y = pd.get_dummies(df.Relationship, prefix='Relationship')
    X = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Relationship', 'Month','Year','Victim Age', 'Perpetrator 
    Age', 'Victim Sex', 'Victim Race', 'Perpetrator Sex', 'Crime Type', 'Perpetrator Race'], drop_first = True )
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[['Month','Year','Victim Age', 'Perpetrator Age', 'Victim Sex', 'Victim Race', 'Perpetrator Sex', 'Crime Type', 'Perpetrator Race']], df.Relationship, test_size=0.1)
    model = LogisticRegression()
    np.isnan(X)
    np.where(np.isnan(X))
    np.nan_to_num(X)
    model.fit(X, y)
```

I am encountering this error:

```py
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-101-68355fc70ed4> in <module>
         15 np.where(np.isnan(X))
         16 np.nan_to_num(X)
    ---> 17 model.fit(X, y)

    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
       1342             _dtype = [np.float64, np.float32]
       1343 
    -> 1344         X, y = self._validate_data(X, y, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=_dtype,
       1345                                    order="C",
       1346                                    accept_large_sparse=solver != 'liblinear')
 
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
        431                 y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
        432             else:
    --> 433                 X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
        434             out = X, y
        435 

    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
         61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
         62             if extra_args <= 0:
    ---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
         64 
         65             # extra_args > 0

    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
        812         raise ValueError("y cannot be None")
        813 
    --> 814     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
        815                     accept_large_sparse=accept_large_sparse,
        816                     dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy,

    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
         61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
         62             if extra_args <= 0:
    ---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
         64 
         65             # extra_args > 0

    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
        661 
        662         if force_all_finite:
    --> 663             _assert_all_finite(array,
        664                                allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
        665 

    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype)
        101                 not allow_nan and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
        102             type_err = 'infinity' if allow_nan else 'NaN, infinity'
    --> 103             raise ValueError(
        104                     msg_err.format
        105                     (type_err,

    ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

I viewed several stackoverflow problems and tried their solutions, but nothing seems to work. This error occurs only when I try to fit X and y in the model.

Comment: Does `np.nan_to_num(X)` occour inplace?

Comment: It does execute when I remove the next line, i.e. model.fit(X, y), but not when I keep it as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix the 'nan' values in your dataset. You are checking for the nan values but not fixing it. Below is sample data.

```
X = np.concatenate((np.arange(1,15),[np.NaN,np.NaN]))
print(np.isnan(X), np.where(np.isnan(X)), np.nan_to_num(X))
```

Output:

```
[False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False  True  True] 
(array([14, 15]),) 
[ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10. 11. 12. 13. 14.  0.  0.]
```

you need to do the next step and assign it back. The code doesnt do 'inplace' assigning.if you dont assign it,there wont be changes in the original array.

```
X = np.nan_to_num(X) # assign it
```

Now if you check X again, there wont be 'nan' values, and then proceed with training the model.

Comment: I'm facing another error: Could not convert string to float. I used the get dummies method, still this error is displayed. Can you please help me solve it?

Comment: Which line of code brings this error? also, show sample data of the column. The string to float error is because of the data types.

Comment: Also, see you are using get_dummies to assign to X and Y but then using df in the train_test split. you should be using X and y in the train_test split.

Comment: So how do I assign it to X and y in train_test_split?

Comment: train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1)

Comment: It's again showing the NaN value error if I replace the df part with x,y, test_size=0.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236735/discussion-between-sonia-samipillai-and-aayush-motiani).